# TTY Login prompt text disappears after 30 seconds

Tags: login, tty

we have an Ubuntu 20.04 which starts only with an TTY and no GUI.

After our customized `/etc/issue` is shown to the user the command prompt will be shown only for 30 seconds. The best solution should be that the login prompt should be shown forever.

The line looks like `hostname login: _` where the underscore is blinking.
After 30 seconds the `hostname login:`  disappears and only the blinking underscore stays: `_`.

After typing a username for example admin, password will be requested

```
admin
Password: _
```

I tried now to update the GRUB_TIMEOUT to -1 but no effect.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Futher I found out that there is another place where a time out is set to 60 seconds in `/etc/login.defs`.

```
#
# Max time in seconds for login
#
# LOGIN_TIMEOUT     60
```

Disabling LOGIN_TIMEOUT had no effect.

Futher I checked `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` where I could find a place with 30 seconds but it was commented out.

```
HoldoffTimeoutSec=60s
```

Changing it to 60 second did not decrease the prompt time.

Does anybody know what can I do now?

Thanks,
Markus

EDIT: The TTY seems to be 1

```
root         903  0.0  0.0   5828  1932 tty1     Ss+  09:17   0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
```

`journalctl -xe -u getty@tty1.service` returns

```
Mai 17 09:17:38 hostname systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
-- Subject: A start job for unit getty@tty1.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit getty@tty1.service has finished successfully.
```

Further I checked `more /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` and `more /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service`

I can not see a prompt timeout and have not done any changes.

I modified `/etc/default/grub` as recommanded and `run sudo update-grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="autoinstall consoleblank=0 ds=nocloud-net;"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

But no behaviour change could be observed.

Comment: Have you checked the status of the `getty@ttyN.service` (replace N by the actual tty number) and/or the journal e.g. `journalctl -xe -u getty@tty1.service` ?

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323258/screen-timeout-for-ubuntu-server-login-screen/1323302#1323302) but with `consoleblank=0` and/or have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408394/my-screen-goes-black-after-30-seconds-of-inactivity-in-ubuntu-22-04).